# gurobi bigM constraint vs. epsilon

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, logical-constraints, big-m, indicator-constraints

I am new to mathematical programming and I am trying to implement case specific constrains in Gurobi with Python.

I am wondering about how I can implement my constraints in the fastest or most common way.

There are three variables:
$$
w_i,w_j \in \mathbb{N},
y_\text{i,j} \in \{0,1\}
$$
The indices $i$ and $j$ referes to fiction tasks since this model takes part of a task scheduling problem. Variable $w$ is a weight of the task and $y$ shows if task $i$ precedes $j$. So there are some other constraints to provide some preceding rules.

I need to implement different constraints (let's say $C_1, C_2, C_3$) depending to those variables:
$$
1: (w_i > w_j) \land (y_\text{i,j} \lor y_\text{j,i}) \rightarrow C_1 \\ 
2: (w_i = w_j) \land (y_\text{i,j} \lor y_\text{j,i}) \rightarrow C_2 \\
3: (w_i < w_j) \land (y_\text{i,j} \lor y_\text{j,i}) \rightarrow C_3  
$$

To implement this constraint I need introduce new binary variables to the model (let's say $a_1,a_2,a_3$) wich are only equal $1$, when the refered case is true. Since Gurobi does not implement strict less or greater operators, [I need to model a bigM constraints](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414392016529-How-do-I-model-conditional-statements-in-Gurobi-) for the variables $a$.

$$
w_i \ge w_j + \epsilon - M(1-a_1) \\
w_i \le w_j + M \times a_1 \\
a_1 \in {0,1} \\
\epsilon << w_i \tag{1}
$$

Since there is a constraint that says, that either $y_\text{i,j}$ or $y_\text{j,i}$, but not both, are equal 1, I plan to implement a constraint for each case with a new binary variable $b$ to represent the logical condition:
$$
b_1 = a_1 \times (y_\text{i,j} + y_\text{j,i})
$$

Finally, I am able to implement each case with an indicator constraint like $b_x \rightarrow C_x; x\in {1,2,3}$

At first, I am wondering if the second equation of EQ:1 can also expressed with epsilon instead of M as $w_i \le (w_j - \epsilon) \times a_1$.

What is the difference?

Second, Is this the correct way to implement a problem like this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the second inequality in (1) as proposed would mean that $w_i \notin (w_j - \epsilon, w_j + \epsilon).$ It would shrink the feasible region in a way that might be detrimental to the solution of the problem.

To get the split you want (into three cases), you could employ three binary variables $z_1,z_2,z_3$ together with the following constraints:
$$ w_i \ge w_j + \epsilon - M(z_2 + z_3)$$
$$ w_j - Mz_2 \le w_i \le w_j + Mz_2$$
$$ w_i \le w_j - \epsilon +M(z_1 + z_2)$$
$$ z_1 + z_2 + z_3 = 1.$$

The last equation can be used to eliminate one of the binary variables. (I would leave it to the presolver to decide whether to do that.) The three $z$ variables correspond to your cases 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Stronger to replace the first three constraints with: $$\epsilon z_1+0z_2-Mz_3\le w_i-w_j \le M z_1+0z_2-\epsilon z_3$$

Comment: Since gurobi does not support constraint modeling with multiple operators, I need to split those constraints. Is this correct?

Comment: @RobPratt: Is it correct, that you mentiond $z_2$ just for completness in your equation? So it is not needed necessary like prubin already mentioned?

Comment: I showed the $0$ coefficient of $z_2$ for completeness, but $z_2$ is still needed in the equality constraint.  You can eliminate any one of $z_i$ by replacing it with $1-z_j-z_k$.  For example, you can replace $z_2$ with $1-z_1-z_3$, but you would still need $z_1+z_3 \le 1$.  You can think of $z_2$ as a slack variable for the equality constraint.

Comment: @Mike Yes, you would split those constraints.

Comment: @prubin, Actually, the variable $z_i$ partitioned the constraints, but would you say please, how it can be represented the relationship between the variables $z_i$ and $y_{ij} \ or \ y_{ji}$ based on the proposed constraints?

Comment: @A.Omidi You need additional variables and constraints. Let's say $s_{i,j,1}, s_{i,j,2}, s_{i,j,3}$ are indicators for conditions $C_1, C_2, C_3.$ You want $s_{i,j,1} = z_{i,j,1} \land (y_{i,j}\lor y_{j,i}).$ If $y_{i,j}$ and $y_{j,i}$ are mutually exclusive, you can get by with three constraints: $s_{i,j,1} \le z_{i,j,1},$ $s_{i,j,1} \le y_{i,j} + y_{j,i},$ and $s_{i,j,1}\ge z_{i,j,1} +y_{i,j} + y_{j,i} -1.$ If they are not mutually exclusive, it gets more complicated.

Comment: @prubin, thanks for your detailed comment. 